# How did the unicode characters endup in the database table column?

Tags: oracle, unicode

Recently I came across a unicode character (\u2019) in a database table column while parsing using Python.

Question: What are the reasons that can result in unicode characters showing up in the database table? Is it data entry issue?

Appreciate any input.

Comment: How are you viewing your data? What is shown if you use `sqlplus` instead? I suspect Python is correctly converting between Oracle varchar types to Unicode objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your Oracle Database you choose a character set which will be used in the SQL **char** datatypes (char, varchar2 etc).

Suppose you chose your character set and you have a table with a column of VARCHAR2 type. Suddenly you need to store some string with non-ASCII symbols not supported by your database (chosen character set). You may convert this string into ASCII string by calling ASCIISTR function for example and store it in your VARCHAR2 column (but it's not a good idea because many SQL built-in functions don't understand '\u2019' (they think it's just 6 symbols)). That's how Unicode may appear in your table column (ASCIISTR converts non-ascii symbols into unicode representation such as '\u2019').

Another option is special Oracle **nchar** datatypes which were designed to store UNICODE without altering global database settings.

Here is the link with Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm